# How to use data from one field in another field in Solr?

Tags: solr

In data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="index" query="select distinct index from (SELECT distinct index FROM street WHERE (substr(code::text, 1, 8)::character varying(8)) = substr('${kladr.code}', 1, 11)
                                    union all 
                                    SELECT distinct index FROM kladr WHERE (substr(code::text, 1, 8)::character varying(8)) = substr('${kladr.code}', 1, 8)
                                    union all 
                                    SELECT distinct index from street_zip where (substr(code::text, 1, 8)::character varying(8)) = substr('${kladr.code}', 1, 11)
                                    union all
                                    SELECT distinct index from street_building where (substr(parent_code::text, 1, 8)::character varying(8)) = substr('${kladr.code}', 1, 8)) as t  
                                    "
           transformer="LogTransformer" logTemplate="street: ${index.index}" logLevel="debug">
        </entity>
```

I need separate entity "index_count" with number of records in entity "index" (it is multivalued field). If I make another SQL query it slows down data import, can I use entity to extract data from it? For example:

```
<entity name="index_count" query="SELECT count(*) from index">
    </entity>
```

Or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the only way, but you could add an [Update+Request+Processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors), that counts the number and populates the index_count field.

It will be fast, but it is more complex to implement, you need to write java code. And if you are using Solrcloud you need to deploy the code to all the nodes etc

Comment: To count a number of values in a multivalued field with URP, you would use CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory  followed by CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory and possibly by DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory (though you could instead set default on the field definition). The full list of the URPs can be found at: http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/